# calculate avg from an input that is a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, average

I have a string that looks like the following

```
s = """nate : 9.5 ,8 ,5 ,8.7
moe : 7 ,6.8 , - ,1
sam : 6 ,4 , ,7.6
cat : 8 ,8.6 ,6 ,2"""
```

for the dash (- ) it should just be removed completely for ex: 6.8, - , 1 should become 6.8,1
for the blank parts, it should have 0 instead for ex 4, , 7.6 should become 4, 0 , 7.6
after that is all done I want to calculate the average of each person and display it as a dictionary

this what I have come up with and I couldn't manage to go any further

```
def avg(s):
    s = s.replace(" - ,", ""). replace(", ,", ", 0 ,")
    s= s.strip().splitlines()
    students={}
    for i in s: 
        s = i.strip().split(":")         
        students[s[0]]= s[1].strip().split(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the scores, skipping `-`, replacing empty strings with `0`, and converting the rest to floats. Then calculate the average by dividing by the length, and store that in the `students` dictionary.

It's easier to replace individual list elements than replacing in the original lines, since your spacing is inconsistent.

```
def avg(s):
    s= s.strip().splitlines()
    students={}
    for i in s: 
        s = i.split(":")
        student = s[0].strip()
        scores = [x.strip() for x in s[1].split(",")]
        scores = [float(score) if score else 0 for score in scores if score != "-"]
        students[student] = sum(scores) / len(scores) if scores else 0
```

Comment: you probably meant to use `x.strip()` in line `scores = [strip(x) for x in s[1].split(",")]`

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question but I also want to remove the lowest grade for each individual before calculating the avg may you please show me how to do that

Comment: Sort the list, then use a slice that starts with element 1. `sorted(scores)[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
# split s into lines and iterate over each line
for line in s.splitlines():

    # init num_scores and total to zero for this student
    num_scores = 0
    total = 0.0

    # get the name and the scores
    name, scores = line.split(" : ")

    # split scores on commas and iterate over each score
    for score in scores.split(","):
        # remove whitespace
        score = score.strip()

        # if we have something and it's not a dash
        if score and score != "-":
            num_scores += 1
            total += float(score)

    # print this student's name and average
    print(f"{name}: average score {total/num_scores}")
```